# How to make a tag finder in python?

Tags: python

how to make a tag finder in python?
my tagged code

```
<h1>hello
<p>world
<b>from
<li>python
```

how to find out all the tags used in the tagged code in python
and output should be
like 
`['h1', 'p', 'b', 'li']`
is there any way to find tags in python

> if any errors in question anyone  can solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `re.findall`:

```py
import re

s = """<h1>hello
<p>world
<b>from
<li>python"""

tags = re.findall(r"<(.*?)>", s)
print(tags) # ['h1', 'p', 'b', 'li']
```